# Installing JRE using Powershell DSC hangs

Tags: powershell, dsc

I'm trying to remote install Java Runtime (8 as it happens) using Powershell DSC on a Windows 2012 R2 box, but it appears to be hanging.

I initially tried to install it using a Chocolatey DSC provider, but that gave me a false success (choco claimed it was installed, but no actual files were unpacked).  I chalked this fact up to this: http://powershell.org/wp/forums/topic/issue-installing-java-32-bit-using-package-resource/#post-23187

So I unpacked the exe and extracted the two java MSIs and my DSC configuration looks like this:

```
    Package java8x86
    {
        Ensure = 'Present'
        Name = 'Java 8 Update 45'
        Path = (Join-Path $localDscFileDir "Java\jre1.8.0_45\jre1.8.0_45.msi")
        Arguments = '/s'
        ProductId = '26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218045F0'
        DependsOn = @("[File]javaMsi")
    }
```

([File]javaMsi copies the .msi files to the remote machine).

When I generate my MOF and Start-DscConfiguration, the output hangs on these lines:

```
VERBOSE: [DEVTEST-3U2LN5Q]:                            [[Package]java8x86]  Parsing 26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218045F0 as an identifyingNumber
VERBOSE: [DEVTEST-3U2LN5Q]:                            [[Package]java8x86] Parsed 26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218045F0 as {26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218045F0}
VERBOSE: [DEVTEST-3U2LN5Q]:                            [[Package]java8x86] Package configuration starting
VERBOSE: [DEVTEST-3U2LN5Q]:                            [[Package]java8x86] Starting C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe with /i "C:\DscFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_45\jre1.8.0_45.msi" /quiet /s
VERBOSE: [DEVTEST-3U2LN5Q]:                            [[Package]java8x86] Starting process C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe with arguments /i "C:\DscFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_45\jre1.8.0_45.msi" /quiet /s
```

I can't even CTRL-C out of that and have to go to the remote machine and kill the Windows Installer process to cause the Start-DscConfiguration to fail

I'm getting to wits end.... it's 2015 and I can't remote setup a Windows box!  So much promised by these technologies....

Comment: You can probably get more logging from msiexec if you put Arguments = "/s /L*v c:\somepath.log". It won't fix the problem but it might help pinpoint what's actually hanging.

Comment: No joy...  The log file gets created, but it's empty...

Comment: Issue _must_ be with the MSI itself...  I've had no trouble doing a full headless remote install of Sql Server.

Comment: No concrete ideas but you could [listen to the soothing voiceover on this video](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToUseProcessMonitorAndProcessExplorer.aspx) while sussing it out with Process Monitor :)

Comment: Thanks Ruben... The JRE requirement is one reason I hate Jenkins....

Comment: @PeterMcEvoy And there was me thinking you'd ported it all to Clojure or Scala :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A year later and I seem to have a solution.  Not sure if the original problem was to do with the version of the installer I was installing or not.. but this seems to work for me - for now:

```
    xRemoteFile javaInstaller {
        DestinationPath = (Join-Path $localDscFileDir "Java\jreInstaller.exe")
        Uri = "http://javadl.oracle.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=211999"
    }
    Package java8
    {
        Ensure = 'Present'
        Name = 'Java 8'
        Path = (Join-Path $localDscFileDir "Java\jreInstaller.exe")
        Arguments = '/s REBOOT=0 SPONSORS=0 REMOVEOUTOFDATEJRES=1 INSTALL_SILENT=1 AUTO_UPDATE=0 EULA=0 /l*v "C:\DscFiles\Java\jreInstaller.exe.log"' #From https://powershell.org/forums/topic/issue-installing-java-32-bit-using-package-resource/#post-39206
        ProductId = '26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F64180101F0'
        DependsOn = @("[xRemoteFile]javaInstaller")         
    }
```

BTW, that download url corresponds to jre-8u101-windows-x64.exe

Comment: Just a note here that the Uri used in the `xRemoteFile` resource needs to point to an offline installer - it will fail otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line

Arguments = '/s'

or else add

Arguments = '/q'

Comment: (as noted in output in OP - those params are being used already)

Comment: Package java8x86
    {
        Ensure = 'Present'
        Name = 'Java 8 Update 45'
        Path = (Join-Path $localDscFileDir "Java\jre1.8.0_45\jre1.8.0_45.msi")
        Arguments = '/q'
        ProductId = '26A24AE4-039D-4CA4-87B4-2F83218045F0'
        DependsOn = @("[File]javaMsi")
    }

Comment: "/q" makes the installer quit with error code 1639, which seems to mean ERROR_INVALID_COMMAND_LINE

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm successfully installing JDK 7 with:

```
Package Java
{
    Ensure = 'Present'
    Name = "Java 7 Update 72 (64-bit)"
    Path = "${InstallerPath}\jdk-7u72-windows-x64.exe"
    ProductId = '64A3A4F4-B792-11D6-A78A-00B0D0170720'
    Arguments = "/s STATIC=1 WEB_JAVA=0"
}
```

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above.

Experienced this before in the past. With MSI/EXE installations via DSC, if you do not pass the correct [arguments] it hangs until all threads are killed on the remote box.

Kill all threads and when next you run conf, force the configuration! 
 *start-dscConf* **-force**